# How does RandomizedSearchCV decide what the best parameters are?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I understand that there is really no "best model" because being the best depends on what evaluation metrics you want to have the best values on. So my question is, what is the metric that `RandomizedSearchCV` uses to decide which are the best parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are referring to the [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html). This uses the given estimator's scoring value by default and you can modify it by changing the `scoring` param.

From Documentation:

> **scoring** str, callable, list/tuple or dict, default=None.
> A single str (see The scoring parameter: defining model evaluation rules) or a callable (see Defining your scoring strategy from metric functions) to evaluate the predictions on the test set.
>
> For evaluating multiple metrics, either give a list of (unique) strings or a dict with names as keys and callables as values.
>
> NOTE that when using custom scorers, each scorer should return a single value. Metric functions returning a list/array of values can be wrapped into multiple scorers that return one value each.
>
> See Specifying multiple metrics for evaluation for an example.
> **If None, the estimator’s score method is used.**

Sklearn's default scoring for a classifier is `accuracy` and for regressor its `r2 score`

For example, you can see that for LinearRegresssion, it is `r2 score` - see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score).